# Correct formatting of date with dayJS

Tags: javascript, dayjs

I am getting an 'Invalid Date' error when passing my date in the format of `1990-12-29Z` into dayJS

I've tried using the various plugins available with no luck, how can I get my date to display as a valid date?

```js
dayjs.extend(timezone)
dayjs.extend(utc)
dayjs.extend(advancedFormat)
dayjs.extend(localizedFormat)
dayjs('2019-01-25Z').format('YYYY-MM-DD Z')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.10.7/dayjs.min.js" /></script>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please update it to a [mcve]

Comment: That's because your date isn't in a valid format: you are missing the HH:MM:SS. If you add `T00:00:00` before Z, then the issue is fixed, i.e.: `2019-01-25T00:00:00Z`